# PHP Zend 2 Cache

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework2, memcached

I am bit new to zend framework and well my question may be silly for some of you, but I hope I will get the right answer to help me move with my project.

My question is about Zend Cache Storage system.
I would like to know, if there is any possibility to use such interface as "The ClearByPrefixInterface" in memcache?
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the part of the page relating to the Memcached adapter:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#the-memcached-adapter

You will see that the "ClearByPrefixInterface" is not listed as one of the interfaces that the adapter implements. You could always write your own interface or just use namespaces with Memcached and it would probably accomplish the same thing as a prefix.